# Change the way randomForest forms a consensus in R

Tags: r, optimization, statistics, modeling

Querying a `randomForest` regression model in R by default returns a (perhaps weighted) mean of all the model's decision tree results. Is there any way to replace this weighted mean with something else, say, the tree output which minimizes a certain function?

Comment: My motivation is that I am using `randomForest` to model the solutions of a minimization problem. This model will hopefully provide a cheap way of computing the map:  `[vector v that specifies a function f_v]-->[vector s that minimizes f_v(s)]. `
Evaluation of `f_v` is cheap but the search space for `s` is large and expensive to search, so I have to model it. 

The function `f_v` has many "cliffs"/discontinuities, so I predict the `randomForest` model will work better if instead of taking the mean, the tree whose solution is minimum among the others is selected.

Comment: Maybe modify by yourself the function `randomForest`? I know that `cutoff` could do the trick for a classification, but not regression

Comment: Have a look at the party::cforest (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/party/party.pdf) that is an implementation of the random forest and bagging ensemble algorithms utilizing conditional inference trees as base learners. This gives you more flexibility. party::prettytree may be also useful to implement your own random forest algorithm.